# Can we add Custom html control like iframe to GOJS Node?

Tags: gojs

I need to add iframe to the GoJS rectangular Node. Any one with the knowledge of GoJs Please help me regarding this .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no, you cannot add HTML to a GoJS Part such as a Node. That would be very inefficient and would prevent rendering to various kinds of surfaces. And it would prevent respecting the intended z-ordering of the Parts.

Comment: Thanks,I researched and found the same .

Comment: Thanks for the topic and for your reply.
So if I get this right, we can only use canvas in the nodeTemplate ?

Comment: You can use a **Picture** to show anything that an Image element can render to a Canvas.